# Haskell - parse error on input `='

Tags: haskell, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

when implementing the code for the "Towers of Hanoi" problem I get the following error message:

```
hanoi.hs:4:24: parse error on input `='
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

---

Here is the code:

```
hanoi 1 i j = [(i, j)]
hanoi n i j = hanoi n' i otherT ++ [(i,j)] ++ hanoi n' otherT j
    where   n' = n-1
            otherT = 1+2+3-i-j
```

---

Any Ideas?

Comment: Seems you have mixed tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor and the compiler see the tabs differently. Avoid using tabs and indent with spaces:

```
hanoi 1 i j = [(i, j)]
hanoi n i j = hanoi n' i otherT ++ [(i,j)] ++ hanoi n' otherT j
    where   n' = n-1
            otherT = 1+2+3-i-j
```

Good editors can be set up to do the right number of spaces automatically when you press tab.